# What is the global default timeout

Tags: python, request, timeout, urllib

Python 3.4 .
Trying to find what is the default timeout in urllib.request.urlopen() .

Its signature is:
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None, [timeout, ]*, cafile=None, capath=None, cadefault=False, context=None)

The [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) says that its "global default timeout", and looking at the code its:
socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT

Still what is the actual value in secs?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I suspect this is implementation-dependent. That said, for CPython:

From [`socket.create_connection`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Lib/socket.py#L485),

> If no *timeout* is supplied, the global default timeout setting returned by :func:`getdefaulttimeout` is used.

From [`socketmodule.c`](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Modules/socketmodule.c#L4154),

```
static PyObject *
socket_getdefaulttimeout(PyObject *self)
{
    if (defaulttimeout < 0.0) {
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);
        return Py_None;
    }
    else
        return PyFloat_FromDouble(defaulttimeout);
}
```

[Earlier](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Modules/socketmodule.c#L719) in the same file,

```
static double defaulttimeout = -1.0; /* Default timeout for new sockets */
```

So it looks like `Py_None`, aka `None`, is the default timeout. In other words, `urlopen` never times out. At least not from the Python end. I guess a timeout can still occur if the networking functions supplied by the OS have timeouts themselves.

---

Edit: oops, I guess I didn't need to go source diving for the answer at all, since it's right there in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket.getdefaulttimeout).

> A value of `None` indicates that new socket objects have no timeout. When the socket module is first imported, the default is `None`.

Comment: so... it looks from Linux kernel?

Comment: That makes for some difficult debugging when you use `urllib2.urlopen(link)` vs `urllib2.urlopen(link, timeout=1)`. Glad I found this answer though.

Comment: @teewuane Not really. You're usually catching stderr for logging anyway. If you now realize that you process idles around, you can send a SIGINT and get the latest trace to your log: `example = request.urlopen([...])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen [...] File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
KeyboardInterrupt`
But I don't think `None` is a sensible default timeout ...

Comment: The default timeout might not be `None`, because `socket.setdefaulttimeout()` may have been called.  So `None` is the "default default" timeout, but if you call `socket.setdefaulttimeout(30)`, the default timeout is now 30 seconds.