# How long does the connection last created by httplib.HTTPSConnection()

Tags: python, parse-platform, httplib, python-sockets

I need to retrieve data from my project set up in Parse.com using Python and the httplib library. Due to my corporate firewall rule, the more popular "httplib2", "requests" and "urllib2" libraries cannot used.

A couple questions regarding httplib and HTTPSConnection:

1. When `conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.parse.com", 443)` is
   called, how long does the `conn` last in the session?
2. Do I need to call `conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.parse.com", 443)` first every time I need to call `conn .request('GET')`?
3. As I am behind a proxy and the network condition is not stable so the `socket.gaierror errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed` exception is occasionally thrown that causes `GET/POST` to fail. How can I check whether the connection is dropped or lost due to network problem?

Comment: I imagine it depends on different factors, the only actual timeout in the source or docs is the `socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT`, https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/httplib.py#l1254.

Comment: Thanks Padraic. Following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649173/what-is-the-global-default-timeout, I think the global default timeout is None.

Comment: Any comment/answer to questions 2 & 3 please?

Comment: yes the default is None. For 2 not really sure, again I imagine there are various factors  but  for 3 just use a try/except and catch the socket error.

Comment: I have already done try and except. Can I check if connection is None or not to see if connection can be established?