# Python 3.4 - failing to connect to http with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to run a simple Python script which connects to a website and reads a document on the website, but it fails. Any help, would be most welcome, thank you!

The code is as follows:

```
import urllib.request

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.py4inf.com/code/romeo.txt')

for line in fhand:
    print (line.strip())
```

And I'm getting the following two error messages:

> TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
> connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
> established connection failed because connected host has failed to
> respond
>
> urllib.error.URLError: {urlopen error [WinError 10060] A connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond}

Comment: works perfectly fine for me, must be a problem with your your connection settings. Do you have a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the windows error, not urllib's one. The latter [has a handy default timeout value of never](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649173/what-is-the-global-default-timeout), but the former [depends on settings of your proxy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811087) (with default being 60 seconds for initial connection and 120 for any further GET requests.

I can't help much with windows, but at least now you know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and tried specifying a timeout in the urllib.request.urlopen, but no dice.

What did work was including a header, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469938/why-does-urllib-request-urlopen-sometimes-does-not-work-but-browsers-work/41470128#41470128). The first answer worked, and so did the second, so I used the simpler, second solution.