# Why does urllib.request.urlopen sometimes does not work, but browsers work?

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-403

I am trying to download some content using Python's `urllib.request`. The following command yields an exception:

```
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.urlopen("https://fpgroup.foreignpolicy.com/foreign-policy-releases-mayjune-spy-issue/").code)
```

result:

```
...
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

if I use firefox or links (command line browser) I get the content and a status code of 200. If I use lynx, strange enough, I also get 403.

I expect all methods to work

1. the same way
2. successfully

Why is that not the case?

Comment: Maybe the site blocks people from scraping by checking header info and all that stuff. Try setting it ?

Comment: @MooingRawr: that's it... please make it an answer.

Comment: also: who are they trying to keep away? Even people like me, who do not get it by themselves, know how to use the internet...

Comment: Answered both your comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely the site is blocking people from scraping their sites. You can trick them at a basic level by including header info along with other stuff. See here for more info.

Quoting from: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#headers

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request

url = 'http://www.someserver.com/cgi-bin/register.cgi'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'
values = {'name' : 'Michael Foord',
          'location' : 'Northampton',
          'language' : 'Python' }
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data, headers)
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
```

There are many reasons why people don't want scripts to scrape their websites. It takes their bandwidth for one. They don't want people to benefit (money-wise) by making a scrape bot. Maybe they don't want you to copy their site information. You can also think of it as a book. Authors want people to read their books, but maybe some of them wouldn't want a robot to scan their books, to create an off copy, or maybe the robot might summarize it.

The second part of your question in the comment is to vague and broad to answer here as there are too many opinionated answers.

Comment: concerning the 2nd question ("who are they trying to keep away"): that was rather a rethorical question ;)

Answer (score 2):

I tried with this code and everything was okay.

I just added `headers` to the request. See the example below:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen, HTTPError
from time import sleep

def get_url_data(url = ""):
    try:
        request = Request(url, headers = {'User-Agent' :\
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.0 Safari/537.36"})

        response = urlopen(request)
        data = response.read().decode("utf8")
        return data
    except HTTPError:
        return None

url = "https://fpgroup.foreignpolicy.com/foreign-policy-releases-mayjune-spy-issue/"

for i in range(50):
    d = get_url_data(url)
    if d != None:
        print("Attempt %d was a Success" % i)
    else:
        print("Attempt %d was a Failure" % i)
    sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
Attempt 0 was a Success
Attempt 1 was a Success
Attempt 2 was a Success
Attempt 3 was a Success
Attempt 4 was a Success
Attempt 5 was a Success
Attempt 6 was a Success
Attempt 7 was a Success
Attempt 8 was a Success
Attempt 9 was a Success
...
Attempt 42 was a Success
Attempt 43 was a Success
Attempt 44 was a Success
Attempt 45 was a Success
Attempt 46 was a Success
Attempt 47 was a Success
Attempt 48 was a Success
Attempt 49 was a Success
```

Comment: Please don’t flood websites by making repeated requests. At least use `time.sleep` between them.

Comment: Ok i'll add a `time.sleep` between each request. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @bfontaine : I won't. I am checking the rss feed for new items first and only download new articles of a certain topic. The problem arose when I first ran the script and requested a few articles by accident.