# python script blocked on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python-3.4, raspberry-pi3

I have some issues with a python script on raspberry pi3.

I send a http request and rarely the script stops on the request function and never quit it.

The code:

```
params = json.dumps({"toto: tata"}).encode('utf8')
head = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.toto.com', data = params, headers = head)
try:
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) # <- here the problem

except:
    print("TCP_IP: may not connected to the internet")
```

For information, I use python3.4 and the OS is Raspbian.

And after few tests:

-The problem appears most of the time at 2AM (GMT+2) (update of the Internet service provider ?)

-I connect the raspberry to the internet through a hub. If I unplug the raspberry from the hub. There is no problem, the script raises an exception after few seconds. BUT if i unplug the hub from the internet. The script stays stop (and for the OS, it's always connected to the internet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when no timeout is given to `urlopen` it will never timeout (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649173/what-is-the-global-default-timeout)). If you give a timeout that should fix your problem.

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, timeout=20)
```

On a sidenode: It is better to catch specific exceptions instead of all, e.g. you would also catch things like ZeroDivisionError which you wouldn't want to catch there.

Comment: Ok thanks, but why an exception appears when the raspberry is unplugged and not when the hub is disconnected to internet ?

Comment: When the raspberry is unplugged the OS will throw an error when attempting to initiate an internet connection. When only the hub is unplugged it looks like it does not abort the connection properly and the OS thinks everything is fine.