# connection timeout error in urllib3 in python

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

I am investigating for default value for timeout in urllib in python.
The default value for timeout is **socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT** and has Value **None**.None means Infinite timeout but what will be the minimum timeout time between retries.

What is default value of GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you could test for it by taking a timestamp before and after a timeout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the global default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29649173/what-is-the-global-default-timeout)

Comment: Yes.The value of default is "None"  which means infinite timeout. Thanks

Comment: backoff_factor was the parameter which i was looking for.Its for the delay between the retries attempted.