# Python FTP (ftplib): Request longer timeout? (WinError 10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host)

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I upload lots of large files (3.4 GB each) to stock footage websites and I wrote a python script to upload them sequentially to each site. Usually it works with no issues, but today, the files failed to upload to one of the sites and returned this error message for each file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\upload.py", line 174, in sequentially_upload_videos_to_sites
    ftp.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(item_name), fp, 8192)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python38\lib\ftplib.py", line 492, in storbinary
    conn.sendall(buf)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

I don't understand why this is happening. My code has not changed from prior times when it was working. My guess is that this is a server issue, but I am not certain. Since these uploads take a long time (my internet connection is slower than it has been in the past, right now it is about 7Mbps up), I'm wondering if the server is just timing me out. **Is there any way to confirm that this is the issue, and if so, how to request a longer timeout time?** For reference, when I uploaded a bunch of smaller files to this website, they all uploaded successfully.

My code is basically this:

```
ftp = FTP()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
ftp.connect(df.loc[site_name]['Host'], 21)
ftp.login(df.loc[site_name]['Username'], df.loc[site_name]['FTP_Key'])
fp = open(item_path, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR {}'.format(item_name), fp, 8192)
fp.close()
```

These websites do not support TLS.

Answer (score 2):

Both the [`FTP` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) and [`FTP.connect` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.connect) have `timeout` parameter (with the same effect).

```
ftp.connect(host, timeout=30)
```

The timeout defaults to the [global default timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29649173/850848).

Answer (score -1):

**Based on the error message and the search results, the error "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" suggests that the FTP server forcibly closed the connection while you were trying to upload the files. This can happen due to various reasons, including network issues, server configuration, or limitations imposed by the FTP server.**

Comment: Sherlock, is that you? I know I am a fool for saying I thought an answer should provide a solution. Perhaps, a script of some sort. Alas, I was again proven wrong and reiterating the error in question seems to be your style. I recommend deletion.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34643943)